# jQuery: How do I dynamically truncate a text if it's content is not visible?

Tags: jquery

How do I dynamically truncate a text if it's content is not visible?

Here are two problems that I have to deal with:

- I don't know the size of the element which text I want to truncate.
- the element has no specific class.

So I need to find out which element is **not** complete visible and I need to find out how much of this element is visible. Then I could add an inline styling to this element.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Please take a look at the script below

[image]
[image]

```js
/* Toggle size of container */
$( ".toggle-size" ).click(function() {
  $( ".container" ).toggleClass( "wide" );
});
```

```css
body{
 text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container{
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container.wide{
  width: 655px;
}

.toggle-size{
  display: block;
  background: #07C;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  cursor: pointer;
}


ul.options{
  width: 100%;
  counter-reset: section;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.options li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #039BE5;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 -4px 0 0 !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle-size">Toggle Size</div>

<div class="container">
<ul class="options">
<li>Option description 1</li>
<li>Option description 2</li>
<li>Option description 3</li>
<li>Option description 4</li>
<li>Option description 5</li>
<li>Option description 6</li>
<li>Option description 7</li>
<li>Option description 8</li>
<li>Option description 9</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the items and check if inner width is enough to display the text

```
var listItems = $("#options li");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var item = $(li);
    if (item.scrollWidth >  $('#options').innerWidth()) {
        //If true, it means text does not fit in the container
        //Apply your class or css here
    }
});
```

I have not tested this but it should give you an idea